# In TextBox only allow numbers

Tags: vb.net

Here is code on how to only allow numbers in a textbox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    '97 - 122 = Ascii codes for simple letters
    '65 - 90  = Ascii codes for capital letters
    '48 - 57  = Ascii codes for numbers

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't understood one thing in here. In `If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then`, why  is the number 8 used? What is represented by 8 in here?
please explain

Comment: Sorry but your question makes no sense. What's this?

Comment: It is the character code for the Backspace key. If you don't allow it then the user couldn't correct typing mistakes anymore. Easy to find out by just trying it.  That the Backspace key generates a KeyPress event, but say Delete and Insert don't, is a bit wonky but goes back to the olden days when people used teletypes to talk to computers.  Note that you also killed copy and paste.

Comment: Never use code you dont understand.  Use the debugger to get an idea about code you paste from the internet.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading your question 2 times, I finally got what you said. You got this code from the Internet or somewhere but you don't know what **8** in `If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then` means right?

Well, the answer is : It means **Backspace** key.

*Mousa Alfhaily* has written the same code without using the ASCII way.
So simply, `If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then` means `If BACKSPACE = False Then` in his code.

For more reference on ASCII values, check this website: [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
Dim BACKSPACE As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        BACKSPACE = True
    Else
        BACKSPACE = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If BACKSPACE = False Then
        Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789"
        If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

A way to handle pasted characters too : Select `textbox1` and go to Properties and then : set the `ShortcutsEnabled` to "False", or you can use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).

I Hope My Code Was Useful To You :)

Comment: this isn't the answer the OP is looking for but nice code, so +1. And I've used your code reference in my answer, hope it's fine

Answer (score -1):

In `ASCII` the numeric values of 0 till 9 are represented as 48 till 57. You can check the list of all `ASCII` in the below link.

[List of all ASCII values](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/)

The value 8 represents `Backspace` key.

Comment: The OP clearly has at best a very vague idea what he is doing and seems to be struggling with Visual Basic and Windows Forms even though the question is tagged with `C`. Yet here you are, providing an answer for JavaScript of all things.